# Why does Google Chrome keep processes running when I don't allow background apps to run after I close?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, process, microsoft-word-2010

Okay so here I close Chrome and it keeps a process running. I tell it to not let anything run after it's closed, but it still does. Also, a lot of the time, it messes with Microsoft Word 2010 and will not let it close and also allow any program to print. What could the issue be?

Comment: try turning off google cloud print in your chrome settings. Let us know if it works.